# python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: python, windows, pip

**I tried the command above but got this error**

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\pip-19.2.3.dist-info\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

**How do I fix this?
And when I try to install other python packages I get the same error message
Please some one should help me with this problem**

Comment: Run with administrator privilege (e.g.: Open your command line with the "Run As Administrator" option). Or do what the message suggest and add the `--user` option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError%3A+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is that your `CMD` process doesn't have high privileges.

The solution is to open the `CMD` as admin, [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/968214/open-cmd-as-admin-with-windowsr-shortcut/968225) or these options:

1. `Win+R`, type `CMD` and press `ctrl+shift+enter`
2. press `start`, look for CMD, right click and `run as administrator`